# Is there a way to automatically reindent a selection while preserving relative indentation?

Tags: indentation

Suppose that I have a file that looks like this:

```
aaa
  bbb
   ccc
```

If I select lines 2 and 3 in visual mode and reindent with `=`, the result is everything in the same line:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Is there a way to ask vim to preserve the relative indentation inside the selection, so the end result looks like the following instead?

```
aaa
bbb
 ccc
```

Basically, I would like to automatically reindent the first line of the selection and then shift the remaining lines left or right by the same amount that the first line was shifted.

Comment: Start reading from `:h 'equalprg'` then revise your question by adding, at the very least, values of `equalprg` and `filetype`.

Comment: If it helps, you can assume that this is a txt text file and that equalprg is unset (which is the default)

Comment: Just select indent with ^V and delete it; or `setl sw=1` and shift with `2<<`

Comment: That does't automatically detect the indentation level of the frst line. I want the first line to end up the same place it would be if we reindented to with =

Comment: Then revenons à nos moutons: what is equalprg, filetype, indentexpr, cindent, etc.etc.